# Google Play Services - BaseGameUtils - GameHelper - Sign In Problems with people outside of the United States

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

So I've had my Android app deployed for a few weeks now, and it uses Google Play Services BaseGameUtils GameHelper to sign in and users can play TurnBasedGames using this API.

The game has been published and have had many friends and family download it, all of which have had no problems signing in, creating games, and playing.

When trying to promote my app, I've had numerous people from out of the United States (i.e. - France, Philippines, ...etc) that have reported that they cannot Sign In at all, most of the time the error does not seem to line up with their reports (i.e. - "Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again." and they say that they have a stable internet connection).

Question being, has anyone had any problems (or success?) using Google Play Services sign in with users outside of the US? I'm not sure if maybe I'm just missing a configuration in my Developer Console to allow internationalization or something simple like that?

Or if anyone else has had more luck being able to debug / handle errors better for users with Sign In errors?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you [localize your app](http://www.androiddocs.com/distribute/tools/localization-checklist.html) to be able to maximize your apps’ distribution potential.

And, if you haven't done so, you may want to also try going through [Launch Checklist](http://www.androiddocs.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html).

From the Checklist, you can check the following:

- [Determine Country Distribution](http://www.androiddocs.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#determine-country)
- [Decide Whether your App will be Free or Priced](http://www.androiddocs.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#decide-price)
- [Start Localization](http://www.androiddocs.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#start-localization)

And since, your app has already been published, you just need to update your app wherein you need to make sure that you [version your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html).

See this [page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en&topic=2365760&ctx=topic) for more information.